# Could not get JSONArray in variable Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, variables

So basically I want to make a TableList from my REST service. The REST service can be decoded by this code block:

```
func getAllParkeergarages(_ completion: @escaping ([Parkeergarage]) -> ()) {
        if let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/parkeergarages") {
           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
              if let data = data {

                  do {
                     let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Parkeergarage].self, from: data)
                    print(res)
                    completion(res)
                    return
                  } catch let error {
                     print(error)
                  }
              }
           }.resume()
        }
```

}

By using this codeblock I can print the whole JSON in my terminal:

```
getAllParkeergarages { (array) in
        print(array)
    }
```

To get the data in a TableView I need to have the data in a variable. But here is where I get stuck. I tried some different methodes like:

```
private var data: [Parkeergarage] = getAllParkeergarages { (array) in
    return array
}
```

but is gives me an error: 'Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type '[Parkeergarage]'. Can someone help me get the result of the function in the variable?

Comment: You need to separate the last code, `private var data: [Parkeergarage]` and then somewhere else `getAllParkeergarages { (array) in  self.data = array }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do

```
private var data: [Parkeergarage] = []
```

in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getAllParkeergarages { (array) in
        self.data = array
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I cannot explain any more.